# images aren't displayed for some reason

Tags: meteor

i have screenShots element in my document that is an array of URLs which am trying to display in the front-end. here is my code

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{#each product.screenShots}}
         <img src="{{product.screenShots}}" alt="">
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

this is what i get int he client side.

[image: this is what i get int he client side.]

i can see the images exists when i enter the URLs.
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Typo? `product.screenShots` can't both be your cursor and the url of an image.

Comment: please post your helper method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said, `screenshots` is an array of URLs, you need to change `src` attribute like this,

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{#each product.screenShots}}
         <!-- Assuming product.screenShots = ["http://url-to-image1.com", "http://url-to-image2.com"] and so on..
         <img src="{{this}}" alt="">
    {{/each}}
</div>
```